# Python Error unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str' on my code

Tags: python

So I'm having a lot of trouble with this code... It gives me an error and I don't see nothing wrong with it! I have about 15 days studying python but I don't really see an error in my code

When I try to run it in the python shell it gives me this error:

> `"unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'"`

Please help me out T____T I'm so frustrated!

```
    @classmethod
    def populationCount(cls):
        print ("The total number of humans is: %d.") %(cls.population)
```

Comment: On which line is the error thrown?

Comment: Code ran correctly for me. I wonder if there's something unusual about the way you are trying to run it.

Comment: Probably all the lines with improper string formatting syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having the problem in this line:

```
print ("The total number of humans is: %d.") %(cls.population)
```

is that the `print` is executed first, with the stuff in the first set of parentheses as an argument. The *return value* of `print` is then used with the `%` operator. `print` returns `None`, so this is what Python is trying to do:

```
None % (cls.population)
```

And you can probably figure out why *that* won't work.

To solve it, put the entire `%` operation *inside* the parentheses so it is done *before* `print` is called. After all, you want the result of the interpolation printed.

```
print("The total number of humans is: %d." % cls.population)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you replace

```
print ("The total number of humans is: %d.") %(cls.population)
```

with

```
print ("The total number of humans is: %d." % cls.population)
```

in your print statements ?

Note: when asking a question, try to trim your code example to the problematic part. It makes it easier for people to help you, and in fact, in some cases, it helps you find the problem before even asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, parenthesis simply change the order of operations unless otherwise stated in code:

```
print ("%s *remains silent*" % (self.name,)) # comma indicates tuple, not change of order
```